# Libparted complaining about GPT signatures on disk

Tags: grub2, partitioning, gpt

This warning comes up while using the Ubuntu studio "Live" from an USB stick, in a PC where the program is installed but the GRUB doesn't work.

What does this mean and how can I fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: the problem is with UEFI and unfortunately I have no experience with it. Something in your setup is wrong could you link the similar issue so I can see if maybe I can help you figure out what to do?

Comment: Please run [Boot-Repair](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log.

Comment: This is normal. I don't understand all the details, but it comes from the fact that it's a hybrid iso and creates media that can boot either efi or bios.

Answer (score 1):

If you prepared a "live" boot disk by using `dd` to copy a `.iso` file to a USB flash drive, then the disk uses a Frankenstein's Monster sort of partition table, and GParted will produce a warning message like that if you launch it on the USB disk (or without explicitly specifying another disk). Thus, this warning *may* be normal, and there's nothing you can do about it. It's also not a bug, because the disk partition table is, as I said, a monstrosity by design. If this is the case, you should ignore the problem and do *not* try to use GParted to modify the partition table on `/dev/sdb` (as noted in the warning), although you can use GParted to modify the partition table(s) on other disk(s).

OTOH, if you prepared your boot disk with a tool like Rufus or UNetbootin, the partition table *should* be more normal. Also, if `/dev/sdb` is a regular internal hard disk rather than a USB flash drive, then the warning you're seeing could indicate a serious partition table problem. I can't offer more specific repair advice because the warning doesn't present the details I'd need to diagnose the issue. You might want to consult [my page on repairing GPT disks](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html) for some general guidance on this topic, and post back with more details if you think you've got a real problem.